# Ist "Guten Hunger!" ausschließlich positiv gemeint?

Tags: idiom

Als ich heute auswärts ein fertig zubereitetes Essen zum Mitnehmen kaufte, war ich etwas überrascht, dass mir der Verkäufer einen "Guten Hunger!" wünschte. Nach kurzer Recherche wurde mir klar, dass "Guten Hunger!" offenbar zumindest regional als völlig neutrales bzw. ebenso positiv konnotiertes Synonym zu "Guten Appetit!" verwendet wird.

Meine Überraschung beruhte jedoch nicht auf der Redewendung selber - sie war mir durchaus bekannt - sondern darauf, dass sie mir bislang stets mit einem anderen Hintergrund begegnet war: Meiner Beobachtung nach wurde mir bislang immer nur genau dann ein "guter Hunger" gewünscht, wenn der Sprecher augenzwinkernd darauf hinauswollte, dass ich eben keinen *Appetit* (lustvolles Verlangen nach Essen, bzw. während dem Essen nach dem nächsten Bissen) haben würde, sondern letztendlich einfach nur hungrig sein würde (z.B. weil das Essen nicht schmeckt, die Portion viel zu klein ist, oder das Essen eine lange Zeit auf sich warten lässt, wenn es denn überhaupt noch eintrifft/serviert wird).

---

Ein typisches Beispiel, welches ich so schon mehrfach erlebt habe: Ein Restaurant, das mit der Anzahl der Gäste offenbar komplett überfordert ist, serviert am Nachbartisch, dessen Bestellungen ungefähr gleichzeitig mit unseren aufgenommen wurden, nach langer Wartezeit zeitversetzt das Essen. Als alle am Nachbartisch fertig sind, ist unser Essen immer noch nicht da. Während sie aufbrechen, sagen uns die benachbarten Gäste in mitleidigem Tonfall: "Na dann ... noch einen guten Hunger!"

Das hatte ich stets so verstanden, dass scherzhaft darauf hingewiesen wird, dass wir eben kein Essen vor uns haben, das unseren Appetit befeuern könnte, und dass uns somit nichts übrig bleibt, als uns an unserem (unbefriedigten) Hunger zu "erfreuen".

---

Daher frage ich mich nun:

Habe ich die vergangenen Jahrzehnte über diese (hier in Südwestdeutschland insgesamt eher seltene) Redewendung falsch verstanden/interpretiert? Oder hat sich vielleicht gerade dort, wo die Redewendung nicht regional typisch ist, eine separate Bedeutung herausgebildet?

Comment: Ich kann dazu nur beitragen, dass diese Redewendung in Österreich nicht gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Ich kenne die negative Konnotation auch nicht, ich kenne das nur mit gleicher Bedeutung wie "guten Appetit" für Leute, denen "guten Appetit" zu etepetete klingt. (Mannheim)

Comment: "Na dann ... guten Hunger !" mit Sarkasmus in einer gestreßten Umgebung ist was anderes als "Guten Hunger !". So intoniert wird jeder Wunsch umgedreht, unabhängig von der Wortwahl. Das kommt in einem Internetpost ohne weitere Klärung halt nicht durch.

Comment: @a_donda: "So intoniert wird jeder Wunsch umgedreht, unabhängig von der Wortwahl." - dieser Aussage kann ich nicht unbedingt zustimmen. Ein genauso intoniertes "Na dann ... noch einen guten Appetit!" würde ich z.B. eher als unpassend empfinden, denn genau der Appetit vergeht ja so langsam. Dann schon eher etwas wie "Frohes Warten!"

Comment: Gegenfrage: Gibt es irgendeine Äußerung, die nicht ironisch gemeint sein kann? Wie soll das gehen? Wer würde ein solches Ironietabu verkünden? Die Kultusministerkonferenz? Wie durchsetzen?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich verstehe den Einwand nicht. Wer hat behauptet, dass irgendetwas nicht ironisch gemeint sein kann?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wie gesagt, für mich hat "Guten Hunger" per se (erste Version der Frage) keine negative Konnotation wenn es nicht explizit mit sarkastischem Tonfall oder Kontext ausgesprochen wird, genauso wie "Mahlzeit" oder "'n Guhden" oder schlicht "Guten Appetit". Ich antworte darauf mit "Danke", genuschelt je nachdem wie voll der Mund halt grade ist :-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich muss hier etwas dagegen halten, ich höre "Guten Hunger" zwar nicht regelmäßig, aber doch häufig genug um es als gebräuchlich zu bezeichnen. Könnte von den vielen deutschen Studenten mitgebracht worden sein, also vielleicht ist es üblicher in Studentenstädten bzw. Gegenden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Dann verstehe ich nicht, was der Inhalt der Frage ist.

Comment: wieso ist hier von Ironie die Rede, *Hunger* ist doch vom Begriff her nicht eben positiv besetzt. Die Frage wäre vorab zu klären, ob die Konnotation in der Wendung abgeschliffen wurde und daher positiv sein kann, ich denke da zuerst an Unterversorgung in der Armee o. ä., oderob das Wort selbst gegenüber Apoetitlosigkeit noch eher neutral war. Die etymologie von appetito ist übrigens nicht weniger verwunderlich, scheinbar verwandt mit *Feder* (also ca. 'Anflüge kriegen'?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, das Bsp. erscheint mir an den Haaren herbei gezogen, und zwar weil die Verwendung wie du schon sagst offensichtlich zu selten ist, um statistisch belastbar zu sein, da es auch spontan so entstehen kann, um nicht zubsagen falsch (dss wäre dann in der That ironisch). Hunger kann schließlich wie auf English auch ein Begehren bezeichnen, insbesondere denn so genannten Heißhunger.

Comment: @vectory: "wieso ist hier von Ironie die Rede, *Hunger* ist doch vom Begriff her nicht eben positiv besetzt." - man wünscht seinennMitmenschen aber im Allgemeinen Positives, somit deutet das Wünschen von etwas nicht eben positiv Besetztem auf Ironie hin.

Answer (score 13):

Ich komme aus Nordostdeutschland und kenne *Guten Hunger!* als informelleres und daher selteneres Synonym von *Guten Appetit!* Ich benutze es zuweilen selber.

Die negative Konnotation in der beschriebenen Situation entsteht für mich nicht schon durch die Redewendung an sich, sondern erst durch den ironischen Tonfall. Das ist vergleichbar mit einer Streitsituation, in der einer dem andern verärgert einen *guten Tag* wünscht und die Tür hinter sich zuknallt.

Comment: "nicht schon durch die Redewendung an sich, sondern erst durch den ironischen Tonfall" - wie bereits in einem Kommentar angemerkt, erschließt sich diese Argumentation für mich noch nicht ganz: Ein mit demselben ironischen Tonfall gesprochenes "Guten Appetit!" wirkt auf mich in den beschriebenen Situationen unpassend bzw. hätte gar keinen Sinn ergeben, ganz im Gegensatz zum beschriebenen "Guten Hunger!" (Aber natürlich könnte es sein, dass es in der Tat gar keinen inhaltlichen Unterschied gibt, und somit auch "Guten Hunger!" an der Stelle eigentlich gar keinen Sinn ergibt.)

Comment: Manche Leute vermitteln den Eindruck, daß sie sogar "Guten Morgen!" ironisch meinen. Das ist eine analoge Situation. Deine Erklärung trifft es.

Answer (score 9):

Ich halte das für ein Synonym von "Guten Appetit". Vielleicht gibt es im Hinblick auf die Verwendung regionale Unterschiede (beispielsweise wird der Ausdruck laut Hubert Schölnast in Österreich nicht verwendet), aber dennoch dürfte "Guten Hunger" in großen Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums bekannt sein. Laut [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7EGuten+Hunger%21&bool=relevanz&sp0=rart_ou) ist er seit ca. 1870 in Gebrauch.

Es gibt mit Sicherheit Situationen (wie in dem Dir erwähnten Beispiel), in denen "Guten Hunger" einen doppelbödig-ironischen Beiklang hat - aber eben nur deswegen, weil er primär eine andere Bedeutung hat. user unknown hat in seinem Kommentar zurecht bemerkt, dass praktisch jede Äußerung ironisch verfremdet werden kann. Weitere Beispiele.

> Na denn Prost!

> Das sieht ja appetitlich aus!

> Lass es Dir mal schmecken!

Answer (score 0):

Das hängt vom Kontext ab. Es kann positiv gemeint sein. Selbstverständlich kann es auch negativ gemeint sein. Ein Beispiel wäre, wenn du "Guten Hunger!" zu einer sehr adipösen Person sagst, die gerade isst und du selbst dabei entsprechend gemein grinst.

Comment: Was unterscheidet das in dieser Situation von "Guten Appetit"?

Comment: Vielleicht ist das nur persönliches Empfinden, aber gegenüber einer adipösen Person ist "Hunger" vielleicht etwas passiv aggressiver als "Appetit".